# Autowired spring bean is not a proxy

Tags: spring, service, proxy, target, autowired

I'm working on a very small application connecting to a MySQL database.

I'm trying to create table record but getting 'no transaction in progress'.

I have all the right stuff in place:

- a service interface MyService and its implementation MyServiceImpl
- I  have annotated the service impl with @Service
- In the controller I used the interface name for the field @Autowired MyService
- I have the correct transaction configuration as it was originally generated by roo
- There is a public method MyService.create(...) which MyServiceImpl implements

But,

When I remote debug and inspect the controller's myService field what I see is something like 
com.some.package.services.MyService@12345 (and NOT something like $Proxy73) which to me is not right, because what should be autowired is the proxy not he target bean (which is what I think this is). If I'm correct then it makes sense that there is no transaction as the annotation would only kick in when invoking a public method annotated with @Transactional on a proxy.

Please tell me why is spring injecting the target bean in this setup.

Thanks

Comment: Is `MyServiceImpl` annotated with `@Transactional`? Do you have `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in XML?

Comment: thanks for the response, yes I have <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have AspectJ-enabled transaction management (`<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" .../>`) application of transactions happens *in-place* in the same class, either during build (compile-time weaving) or on startup (load-time weaving).

No new classes are created (like when using [cglib](/questions/tagged/cglib)) and no proxies (like with ordinary interface-based AOP in Spring). Instead bytecode of `MyServiceImpl` was modified directly without you even noticing. Unfortunately the only way to see AOP is to decompile your classes. If you use `javap -c MyServiceImpl` you'll find plenty of references to Spring transaction layer.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, what you say makes sense so thanks for that. I de-compiled the class is this what you meant: AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().ajc$before$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(this, ajc$tjp_0); localJobSpec1 = (JobSpec)super.create(jobSpec); } catch (Throwable localThrowable) { AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$2$2a73e96c(this, localThrowable); throw localThrowable; } AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().ajc$after etc etc

Answer (score -4):

If you are using Spring MVC, make sure to scan specific controller classes alone in servlet context file. Otherwise it will scan 2 times and transaction is not available on the application context.

Comment: Please stop posting the same copy/pasted answer everywhere. Try to ensure it is really relevant to the current question.