# Test Spring Boot cache in Kotlin and JUnit5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit5, spring-cache

I have a simple repository and it's interface written in Kotlin to get a list of sites from db; and I cache response with Spring cache:

```
interface IRepository {
  fun sites(): List<String>
}

@Repository
class Repository(private val jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate) : IRepository {
  private val sites = "SELECT DISTINCT siteId FROM sites"

  @Cacheable(value = ["sites"], key = "sites")
  override fun sites(): List<String> = jdbcTemplate.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sites, String::class.java)
}
```

Now I want to test that caching is actually working. As base for test I used [How to test Spring's declarative caching support on Spring Data repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221569/how-to-test-springs-declarative-caching-support-on-spring-data-repositories) but direct implementation resulted in error of repository being a proxy and not repository. So my current attempt is:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
class RepositoryCacheTests {
  @MockBean
  private lateinit var repository: Repository

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var cache: CacheManager

  @EnableCaching
  @TestConfiguration
  class CachingTestConfig {
    @Bean
    fun cacheManager(): CacheManager = ConcurrentMapCacheManager("sites")
  }

  @Test
  fun `Sites is cached after first read`() {
    // Arrange
    whenever(repository.sites()).thenReturn(listOf(site, anotherSite))

    repository.sites()

    // Assert
    assertThat(cache.getCache("sites")?.get("sites")).isNotNull
  }
```

But cache is empty and not populated after first read. What am I missing in my setup?

Update:

Using George's suggestion I updated the test (and code for easier mocking). I also had to add `@Bean` for repository in configuration because of `Could not autowire. No beans of 'Repository' type found.` without it.

```
  @Cacheable(value = ["sites"], key = "'sites'")
  override fun sites(): List<String> = jdbcTemplate.query(sites) { rs, _ -> rs.getString("siteId") }
```

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
class RepositoryCacheTests {
  @MockBean
  private lateinit var jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var repository: Repository

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var cache: CacheManager

  @EnableCaching
  @TestConfiguration
  class CachingTestConfig {
    @Bean
    fun testRepository(jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate): Repository = Repository(jdbcTemplate)

    @Bean
    fun cacheManager(): CacheManager = ConcurrentMapCacheManager("sites")
  }

  @Test
  fun `Sites is cached after first read`() {
    whenever(jdbcTemplate.query(any(), any<RowMapper<String>>())).thenReturn(listOf(site, anotherSite))
    repository.sites()
    assertThat(cache.getCache("sites")?.get("sites")).isNotNull
    repository.sites()
    verify(jdbcTemplate, times(1)).query(any(), any<RowMapper<String>>())
  }
}
```

Now the test does not even start:

```
Error creating bean with name 'RepositoryCacheTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'testRepository' is expected to be of type 'Repository' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52'
```

Update 2:

As George points, solution is (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911329/492882 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911329/492882)

```
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var repository: IRepository
```

Comment: 1. What is `repository.read(site, locale)`? This method does not exist in the `Repository` class.
2. Results of the `repository.sites()` call are stored in the "site" cache under the "site" key while you are trying to retrieve it from the "templates" key.

Comment: Sorry! I tried to simplify code for this question as much as possible and copied wrong method name. I updated the question (it still stands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking your test subject `Repository repository`. This should be the real object initialized by Spring so it has caching. You need to mock the `JdbcTemplate` that your test subject is calling.

I don't really know kotlin syntax, so bear with me. Here's how your test should look like:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
class RepositoryCacheTests {
  @MockBean
  private lateinit jdbcTemplate: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
  @Autowired
  private lateinit var repository: IRepository

  @Autowired
  private lateinit var cache: CacheManager

  @EnableCaching
  @TestConfiguration
  class CachingTestConfig {
    @Bean
    fun cacheManager(): CacheManager = ConcurrentMapCacheManager("sites")
  }

  @Test
  fun `Sites is cached after first read`() {
    // Arrange
    whenever(jdbcTemplate.queryForList(any(), String::class.java)).thenReturn(listOf(site, anotherSite))

    repository.sites()

    // Assert
    assertThat(cache.getCache("sites")?.get("sites")).isNotNull

    //Execute again to test cache.
    repository.sites()
    //JdbcTemplate should have been called once.
    verify(jdbcTemplate, times(1)).queryForList(any(), String::class.java)
  }
```

Comment: What you say makes sense! I tried to follow your advice and failed :(

Comment: What exactly failed?

Comment: I updated the question with you suggestions and new failure (BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException for repository)

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509142/beannotofrequiredtypeexception-due-to-autowired-fields You just have to use the interface instead of the class: `repository: IRepository`

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. Do you want me to accept your answer right away; or you want to update it so that solution is in the answer and not in the comment? (it's  `update 1` with `repository : IRepository`

Comment: Thank you for your help and time!