# Testing SpringBoot @Cacheable functionality

Tags: spring-boot, caching, junit5

I've implemented Cache for some DDBB access on a Spring Boot application.
So far it's been working, but we want to ensure it's not disabled in the furture, so I want to add a JUnit test to assert it on every compile round.

I can't make it work. I've followed instructions from other SO threads with no success
[Test Spring Boot cache in Kotlin and JUnit5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414713/test-spring-boot-cache-in-kotlin-and-junit5)

Our relevant stack for this matter is SpringBoot 2.7, JUnit 5

The @Cacheable enabled class is this

```java
@Component
public class AttributeDatabaseAdapter implements AttributePort {
    
    final AttributeRepository repository;
    final AttributeMapper mapper;
    
    
    
    public AttributeDatabaseAdapter(AttributeRepository repository, AttributeMapper mapper) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }
    

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = CacheConfig.CACHE_ATTRIBUTE, key="{ #attributeName, #userId }")
    public Attribute getActiveAttributeByName(String attributeName, Integer userId) {
        List<AttributeEntity> listAttribute = repository.findAll(AttributeSpecifications.getFilterFromSelector(attributeName));
        
        if (!listAttribute.isEmpty()) {
            if (listAttribute.size() == 1) {
                return mapper.toDomainObject(listAttribute.get(0));
            } else {
                throw new NonUniqueResultException("A unique result was expected but more elements were found.");
            }
        }
        return new Attribute();
    }

}
```

Now for testing, I've build Up this JUnit file, following this [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-testing-cacheable) tutorial and spiced-up with this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63414713/test-spring-boot-cache-in-kotlin-and-junit5)

```java
@ContextConfiguration
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class AttributeDatabaseAdapterTest {

    @Mock
    private static AttributeRepository repositoryMock;

    @Spy
    private static AttributeMapper attributeMapper = new AttributeMapperImpl();
    
    @EnableCaching
    @Configuration
    @Import({AttributeMapperImpl.class})
    public static class CachingTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(CacheConfig.CACHE_ATTRIBUTE);
        }

        @Bean
        public AttributeRepository repository() {
            return repositoryMock;
        }
    }
    
    // OPTION 1
    // @InjectMocks private AttributeDatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;
    
    // OPTION 2
    @Autowired private AttributePort databaseAdapter;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        reset(repositoryMock);
    }
    
    private final static AttributeEntity ATTR1 = AttributeEntity.builder().techId(1).build();
    private final static AttributeEntity ATTR2 = AttributeEntity.builder().techId(2).build();

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Calling DatabaseAdapter two times makes one call to repository")
    void multiple_calls_must_hit_databaseadapter_only_once() {
        when(repositoryMock.findAll(any(Specification.class))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(ATTR1));
        
        // Mapper makes new instances, so can't compare objects. Must compare values
        assertEquals(ATTR1.getTechId(), databaseAdapter.getActiveAttributeByName("TEST", 1).getTechId());
        assertEquals(ATTR1.getTechId(), databaseAdapter.getActiveAttributeByName("TEST", 1).getTechId());
        assertEquals(ATTR1.getTechId(), databaseAdapter.getActiveAttributeByName("TEST", 1).getTechId());
        
        verify(repositoryMock, times(1)).findAll(any(Specification.class)); // Fails on OPTION 1
    }
    
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Assert Repository must return one single result")
    void filtering_Must_Return_single_Result() {
        when(repositoryMock.findAll(any(Specification.class))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(ATTR1, ATTR2));
        assertThrows(NonUniqueResultException.class, () -> databaseAdapter.getActiveAttributeByName("TEST", 1));
    }
}
```

Both OPTION 1 and OPTION 2 fails:

1. OPTION-1 complains on test 1, as assert finds 3 hits on DatabaseAdatper, expected 1. Seems SpringBoot @Cacheable is not working. Maybe SpringBoot Context is not running. Test 2 runs perfectly
2. OPTION-2 doesn't start. Complains on missing AttributePort bean. Seems Autowiring cannot find implementation properly

So, what I am missing?

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509142/beannotofrequiredtypeexception-due-to-autowired-fields) OPTION-2 must declare a varaible using the interface instead of the implementation for SpringBoot to autowire properly. but it's not working. OPTION-1 seems @Cacheable not being initialized

Comment: Option 1 doesn't use Spring (regardless of the fact you are running it with Spring, using `@InjectMocks` gives control of the instance creation to Mockito and ignores Spring). Option 2. there aren't enough beans and you aren't initializing the mocks you are returning using (there is no `MockitoExtension` in your `@ExtendWith`). All in all your test is a bit in limbo it isn't a proper Spring test, nor is it a proper Mockito test hence both fail. To fix add `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` or let the config create the mocks (by manually mocking them).

Comment: Additionally I fail to see how this test will test the accidental disablement. It will only test if someone removes the `@Cacheable` it doesn't test your actual configuration if someone specified `NONE` as the cacheprovider, or removed `@EnableCaching`

Comment: **@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)** seem not valid for caching
Thank you anyway @M.Deinum

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for caching, you can have multiple `@ExtendWIth` that is one of the options you have with JUnit5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 won't work because if you use `@InjectMocks`, you're letting Mockito create an instance of your `AttributeDatabaseAdapter`, which won't be a Spring bean (and thus `@Cacheable` will be ignored).

Option 2 is the right solution. However, right now it isn't working because nowhere in your test you tell the Spring container to include `AttributeDatabaseAdapter`. The easiest way to do this is to extend the `@Import` annotation on your configuration. For example:

```java
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
@Import({AttributeMapperImpl.class, AttributeDatabaseAdapter.class}) // Change this
public static class CachingTestConfig {
    // ...

}
```

---

There are also a few other caveats in your code.

1. You're combining Mockito-annotations with Spring-configuration which won't work because you're not using the `MockitoExtension` (nor should you if you want to test `@Cacheable`). This means that:

   - You shouldn't use `@Mock` but use `@MockBean` in stead (you can remove the `repository()` method from your `CachingTestConfig`).
   - You shouldn't use `@Spy`. Right now it doesn't even do much because you're already importing the `AttributeMapperImpl` bean through the `@Import` annotation so you could just remove the spy alltogether.
2. Ideally you use `@TestConfiguration` in stead of `@Configuration` in your `CachingTestConfig`.

Comment: Bravo! You are right
I've made some changes and managed to get it working
BUT:
I had to manually add an _AttributeRepository_ Bean, because adding **@MockBean** leadded to this error:

The field private static com.me.persistence.repository.AttributeRepository com.me.persistence.AttributeDatabaseAdapterTest.repositoryMock cannot have an existing value. Any Ideas?

Comment: Sucess! I just removed static from _@MockBean private static AttributeRepository repositoryMock_ and it's working not. Thank you so much!